# Permission denied (publickey) after rsync

Tags: ssh, rsync, amazon-ec2

**DISCLAIMER: this may not be fully Ubuntu related but for some reason serverfault gives me an error when posting, plus I think some of you may have stumbled on something like this before**

I'm experiencing a strange issue.
I have multiple ec2 instances that I'm managing and I had to copy some hidden files from an Ubuntu to an Amazon Linux instance.

The way to go should be rsync AFAIK, and since the pem files are on my local machine - Mac OS X 10.10.5 - I did what I had to do by doing:

```
rsync -rave "ssh -i keyfile1.pem" ubuntu@firstmachineip:folder_inside_home/ local_folder/
```

and then

```
rsync -rave "ssh -i keyfile2.pem" local_folder/ ec2-user@secondmachineip:
```

which both succeeded.

The problem is that when sshing again to the second machine (the first is fine) gives me the vague

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Note that before rsyncing the connection worked with no problem and even if the key file ever got corrupted I restored it from a backup and took care of `chmod 600 keyfile2.pem` and even tried `chmod 400 keyfile2.pem`

I will also leave the last part of the output of `ssh -vvv -i keyfile2.pem ec2-user@secondmachineip` after it established that the fingerprint is known:

```
debug1: Host 'secondmachineip' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/thevet/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug2: bits set: 494/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: keyfile2.pem (0x0), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: keyfile2.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA *here goes the rsa*
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any clue what the hell has happened? I'm clueless.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that either there is a protective feature or a bug with Rsync when transferring using -a into the root folder.

Given a local folder call Music containing cow.txt

```
rsync -a Music/ root@134.209.12.183:/usr/
```

moves the cow.txt file in the music folder in to usr/ and I can still log in.

```
rsync -a Music/ root@134.209.12.183:/root/
```

moves the cow.txt file into /root/ and the authorized keys are not affected but I cannot log in subsequently with ssh@root134.209.12.183.

I'm not sure why this happens and couldn't see anything in the log on the server that would explain it.

But at least it's easy to avoid the issue

Both the remote and local server and running
rsync version 3.1.1 protocol version 31

on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site, not a discussion forum. What you have posted as an answer does not answer the original question. Please see the [Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help) for how to ask questions and answer them in this site. Please note bug reports are off-topic here.

Comment: I feel the knowledge is pertinent to question as if one uses rsync in the way I described, you get the resulting ssh permission denied situation in the question. The first answer suggest that the .ssh configuration is overwritten however in my tests this was not occurring. True I don't know why the error occurs. Perhaps someone else would after reading this. It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: just saw this. I agree it's not really a solution but it does describe the issue and shows a workaround. I ended up recreating the instance (it was 2 years ago) but i will accept this answer as it gives options to avoid the issue I had and is more relevant than the other answer. I don't really think there would have been a solution that would have allowed me to login to that instance without recreating it

Answer (score 0):

The `rsync` command, override the `ssh`  configuration in the second-remote-host /home/username/`.ssh`  with the content of `.ssh` folder from the first-remote-host

A way to confirm it, will be:

- copy (using rsync) from firstmachineip to local_folder
- remove `.ssh` folder from local_folder
- copy (using rsync) from local_folder to secondmachineip

Comment: I see... Any way I could solve that problem?

Comment: @TheVet - the simplest solution I can think, is to remove the `.ssh` folder from the local_folder before coping to the 2nd machine (see updated answer)

Comment: Ok sorry I now get what you're saying, I misunderstood the situation there. I'm not copying any .ssh folder and I can confirm that by looking at the files i've copied from the first machine with `ls -a`. In fact I'm copying from a subfolder (not .ssh/) of the first machine's home directly to the second machine's home, but it's just non-hidden folders and hidden .htaccess files

Comment: And anyways I'm basically locked out of the 2nd server so there's no way I could edit the files there. I just hoped it was something related to my local machine